# Modal abre sobreposta por fundo preto

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

As minha modais estão abrindo debaixo do fundo preto, assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso eu tire o **z-index:1040** do código abaixo, o fundo preto some:

```
.modal-backdrop {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1040;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

Entretanto gostaria que ela abrisse normalmente, com o fundo preto por baixo da modal.

Comment: Você esta usando bootstrap com jquery-ui ou blockUI ? Existe um conflito que ocorre exatamente isso, ele aciona o background errado.

Comment: @RBoschini  bootstrap + jquery-ui

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Comment: @gustavox segui todas as dicas, mas ainda não consegui resolver.

Comment: Não pode postar o HTML? Pelo menos a parte relevante... @Bia

Comment: outra coisa que dá pra fazer é passar para o modal o fade={false}, como abaixo:
<Modal isOpen={linkOpen} fade={false} toggle={toggle}>

Answer (score 1):

Tradução da principal resposta [desta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636667/bootstrap-modal-appearing-under-background) do SOen:

Este comportamento ocorre quando o modal tem uma posição fixa ou relativa, ou está dentro de um elemento com posição fixa ou relativa.

**Verifique se o modal e todos os seus elementos pai estão posicionados da forma padrão para resolver o problema.**

Aqui estão algumas maneiras de fazer isso:

1. A maneira mais fácil é simplesmente mover a `div` modal para fora de quaisquer elementos com posicionamento especial. Um bom lugar pode ser um pouco antes da tag de fechamento `</body>`.
2. Alternativamente, você pode remover os `positions`: as propriedades CSS do modal e as *herdadas* (fiquei em dúvida aqui na tradução...), ​​até que o problema desapareça. Contudo, isso pode alterar a aparência da página.

> update

E tem uma [outra resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26921360/4734177) mais abaixo, que talvez possa ajudar, pelo que você descreveu na pergunta:

...

O que funcionou: setei o `z-index` do `.modal-backdrop` para `-1`.

```
.modal-backdrop {
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Comment: dessa forma apenas tira o fundo preto.

Comment: Qual forma? Mudando o `z-index`? Você tentou colocar a div do modal log antes do `</body>`? Poste o HTML na pergunta, e se souber, crie um fiddle, que isso pode ajudar bastante...

Answer (score 1):

Eu estava com o mesmo problema porém eu descobri o que é, nesse caso tem alguma *div* ou *ul* ou *li* ou algum outro elemento que esta com `position:absolute;` no *css* que está fazendo esse fundo ficar sobreposto , então você tem que  criar uma nova regra com `position:static;` para poder liberar a posição como todas estáticas.

**Exemplo:**

```
<style>
.dropdown-menu {
position:static !important; //aki faz funcionar o madal e so por estatic

}
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}
.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Eu resolvi isso modificando a classe WRAPPER do bootstrap. Apenas deletei o z-index -1 dela.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).